# How to prove that a set of lines have the same convex hull as a set of the line endpoints with induction

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-hulls

This is a question 1.6a from the book [Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Computational%20Geometry%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications%20%282nd%20ed.%29%20%5Bde%20Berg%2C%20van%20Kreveld%2C%20Overmars%20%26%20Schwarzkopf%202000-02-18%5D.pdf)

> 1.6 In many situatuions we need to compute convex hulls of objects other than points.
>
> a. Let S be a set of n lines segments in the plane. Prove that the convex hull is exactly the same as the convex hull of the 2n end points of the segments.

However I need to do this with induction proof using convex combinations.

I've made the base case where we only have 2 points so that $a_1 + a_2 = 1 => a_1*x_1 + (1-a_1)x_2$ defines the convex combination

so we get $\sum_i^n a_i*x_i$ is the convex combination för n points.
n = p and we get $\sum_i^p a_i*x_i$

$\sum_i^{p+1}a_i*x_i = \sum_i^{n}a_i*x_i + a_{i+1}*x_{i+1}$ is the induction step for the convex combination.

However as of my understanding this only proves a convex hull exists for the points and not set of lines necessarily have the same convex hull as the points

Edit:
Ok, so i found a possible solution with the help from @SomeCallMeTim
So $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i*x_i + a_{2i}*x_{2i})$ is the convex hull of S
and $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} (a_i*x_i) $ is the convex hull of S'
Therefore to prove $S' = S \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i*x_i + a_{2i}*x_{2i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2n} (a_i*x_i)$ must be true.

Induction proof:
Base case: $n = 1 \rightarrow a_1*x_1+a_2*x_2 = a_1*x_1+a_2*x_2$
$n = p \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{p} (a_i*x_i + a_{2i}*x_{2i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2p} (a_i*x_i)$
$n = p + 1 \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{p+1} (a_i*x_i + a_{2i}*x_{2i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{2p+2} (a_i*x_i) \rightarrow$
$\sum_{i=1}^{p+1} (a_i*x_i) +\sum_{i=p+2}^{2p+2}( a_{i}*x_{i}) =\sum_{i=1}^{2p+2} (a_i*x_i) \rightarrow$
$\sum_{i=p+2}^{2p+2}(a_i*x_i) = \sum_{i=p+2}^{2p+2}(a_i*x_i)$
Is this correct or does anything  need improvement

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Ok, I will try to clarify to what I've done and what i am stuck on. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I think you are very much on the right track. A quick overview: Hopefully it is clear, and not too hard to prove, that the convex hull of the line segments must contain the convex hull of the endpoints. This follows simply from the endpoints being contained in the lines. Next, you want to show the converse, that the convex hull of the lines is contained in the convex hull of the endpoints. Thus, you take a point in the convex hull of the lines, and show it is contained in the convex hull of the endpoints, using its convex combination.

Comment: If the point *has* a convex combination from the endpoints, it lies in their convex hull, and thus you are done.